# How to size the image resolution in Latex?

Tags: graphics, floats, png, resolution, large-files

I'm using overleaf to write the report of a big group project. There are lots of figures in the file. Thing is, I noticed that the pdf file output is becoming larger and larger due to the large png files that are imported. (already 30MB with only 17 pages) Most of the figures are scaled fairly small so I don't actually need the full resolution available.
Is there any way latex can change their resolution for me when I compile? In best case scenario, set their resolution based on the eventual size in the pdf file? 
Resizing them all manually is not really an option because there are about 40-60 figures already.

Thanks in advance
Siebe

The way every figure is currently imported is with:

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{Figures/Solution/Antenna/Monopole/NEC/MonopoleModel.png}
\caption{Monopole antenna model in NEC}
\label{fig:antenna_nec_monopole}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: you need to do it externally, the  number of files should not be an issue you can script a loop  calling image magic convert or similar tools

Comment: More to the point, scaling the images has no effect on PDF file size.  You can verify by zooming in on the images to see the original resolution.